# Is it possible to use .properties files in web.xml in conjunction with contextConfigLocation parameter?

Tags: spring, properties, web.xml

Here is part of my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:application-config.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

application-config.xml uses property placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/db.properties"/>
```

Is it possible somehow to define which properties file to use in web.xml rather than in application-config.xml?

Comment: how did you fetch db.properties in web.xml? I tried with ${property.name}. But its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ServletContextParameterFactoryBean` to expose `context-param` value (it also requires full form of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of simple `context:property-placeholder`):

```
<bean id = "myLocation" class = 
    "org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextParameterFactoryBean">
    <property name="initParamName" value = "myParameter" />
</bean>

<bean class = 
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" ref = "myLocation" />
</bean>
```

Or use Spring 3.0's EL:

```
<bean class = 
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value = "#{contextParameters.myParameter}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: if you guys can clarify this answer I'm sure it'll help a lot of people.

Answer (score 4):

Totally agree with axtavt. So all the info combined the most simple solution with Spring 3.0 thus is:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="#{contextParameters.propertiesLocation}"/>
```

with

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>propertiesLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:properties/db.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in web.xml.

Comment: So this is enough to read properties from that db.properties-file and to use them in both applicationContext.xml and web.xml by `${yaddayadda}`?

Comment: @Oliver: as you mentioned above have a config.properties which need to read in web.xml and specified context param in web.xml and context-property in app.xml..as a init parameter using <param-value>${SystemInfo}</param-value> in web.xml but it is not displaying the value it display ${SystemInfo}..

Comment: Hi there. Is there anything else needed to get this to work? When I do this, I get `Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{contextParameters.propertiesLocation}]`